# Update values of rows not selected simultaneously

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I can assign `eventIndex` as follows for row selected , when user selects a row  and at same time for remaining rows, I went to set `eventIndex` like this which I am not able to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
var eventSchOnc :EventScheduleOnc?
 do {

  // for selected row
      let endRow = self.myEventTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) – 1
     eventSchOnc?.setValue(endRow , forKey: "eventIndex")

   //then update other rows as follows
    eventSchOnc?.eventIndex =  (eventSchOnc?.eventIndex)! - 2
     try context.save()
      }
     catch{}
     }
```

Is there any condition that can help me assign indexes for rows not selected simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet provided, you declare eventSchOnc in

```
var eventSchOnc :EventScheduleOnc?
```

but then you never assign anything to it, so it is `nil`

Maybe you forgot the initializer?

```
var eventSchOnc = EventScheduleOnc()
```